# Magento - menu display category and products in category

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have 2 products categories in my Magento admin. Category one, has 5 products and category 2 has 8 products.

What I'd really like to do, is to have a menu, that displays both categories and then a drop down menu, that displays the products in each category.

Is this possible? I've looked everywhere but found no real examples

Comment: If you edit your question to contain the code that you tried, you'll probably have a little more luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible but you would have to implement this yourself if you can find no examples :).

Suggestion:
You could maybe extend/override the function `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation->_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml` to render its products in the dropdown menu instead of its subcategories.

Comment: Yeah I've found an example here: http://asia-connect.com.vn/2009/07/magento-menu-customization-with-product-list/ but when I use the code, it displays the categories first and then the products underneath. I might look into a custom method or as you said, override the renderCategoriesMenuHtml

Comment: Would someone be able to assist me in getting this to work? Thanks

Comment: I managed to find a work around. Using $newCarCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(CATEGORY_ID);
            $newCarCollection = $newCarCollection->getProductCollection(); '

Answer (score 1):

I used the call to:

```
 $newCarCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(CATEGORY_ID);
 $newCarCollection = $newCarCollection->getProductCollection();
```

Then looped through the ids. Was pretty simple but effective

Thanks all for looking